# How would I create a timesheet and tie each input value to the respective date?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wish to create a timesheet grid. Basically, a grid that displays the current week and the project you're working on as such: https://jsfiddle.net/ho9a8neq/
How do I set up v-model so I can correctly send the value with the corresponding date to a database?
Something like

```
[
  {date: "jan-1": 8, project: 1},
  {date: "jan-2": 10, project: 1},
  {date: "jan-3": 10, project: 2}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to collect data for different projects during a timeline and track the day of each one the solution I propose consists in the following data structure:

```
day = ''
week = [day, day, day]
project = [week, week, ...]
```

> For the sake of simplicity it limits to adding future weeks. Its possible to change this, but it will require more complexity on the models and I don't think it will help to understand how to bind data to the model.

For each week there must be a model that retains each day data, this is done creating an array of empty strings:

```
week: ['','','','','','','']
```

Each project can contain several weeks:

```
data: [week, week, week]
```

When the user creates a new project it must replicate the project model considering the current week:

```
_.cloneDeep(project(this.weekNum, this.rows.length))
```

Now, with the data structure in place, bind the view to it:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 35px;" v-model="row.data[weekNum][i]">
```

---

*See snippet to understand how everything ties together:*

```js
const weekData = () => new Array(7).fill('');

const project = (weekNum, id) => ({
  project: "first",
  id,
  data: Array(weekNum + 1).fill([]).map(weekData)
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    weekNum: 0,
    rows: [_.cloneDeep(project(0, 0))]
  },
  methods: {
    addProject() {
      window.pp = _.cloneDeep(
          project(this.weekNum, this.rows.length)
        )
      this.rows.push(
        window.pp
      );
    },
    deleteRow(key) {
      this.rows.splice(key, 1);
    },
    nextWeek() {
      this.weekNum++;
      this.rows.forEach(_project => {
        if (!_project.data[this.weekNum]) {
          _project.data.push(weekData());
        }
      });
    },
    prevWeek() {
      this.weekNum--;
      this.rows.forEach(row => {
        if (!row.data[this.weekNum]) {
          row.data.unshift(weekData());
        }
      });
    },
    dates(dateFormat, weekNumber) {
      let startOfWeek = moment().startOf('week').add(weekNumber, "week");
      const endOfWeek = moment().endOf('week').add(weekNumber, "week");
      const days = [];
      while (startOfWeek <= endOfWeek) {
        days.push(startOfWeek.format(dateFormat))
        startOfWeek = startOfWeek.clone().add(1, 'd');
      }
      return days
    },
    log() {
      const output = _.reduce(this.rows, (result, row) => {
        const project = {
          project: row.id
        };
        const startWeek = moment().startOf('week');
        const weekDays = [];
        row.data.forEach((week, weekIdx) => {
          week.forEach((data, dataIdx) => {
            if (data === '') return;
            weekDays.push({
              data,
              project: row.id,
              day: startWeek.clone().add(weekIdx, 'week').add(dataIdx, 'd').format('MMM D')
            });
          });
        });
        return [...result, ...weekDays];
      }, []);
      console.log(output)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.22/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- for the sake of simplicity limit the date to future weeks -->
  <button @click="prevWeek" :disabled="weekNum < 1">Previous week</button>
  <button @click="nextWeek">Next week</button>
  <button @click="addProject">Add project</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th v-for="(day, i) in dates('MMM D', weekNum)" :key="i">{{day}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, key) in rows" :key="key">
        <td>Project {{key}}</td>
        <td v-for="(n,i) in dates('YYYY-MM-DD', weekNum)" :key="`${row.id}-${i}`">
          <input type="text" style="width: 35px;" v-model="row.data[weekNum][i]">
        </td>
        <td><button @click="deleteRow(key)">x</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button @click="log()">log</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What is lodash used for?

Comment: Also, what makes it "tricky" if I wish to show previous weeks as well?

Comment: Lodash is added only to `cloneDeep` the object since there is a one-line solution to do that in vanilla js.

Regarding the previous weeks, it's a limitation on how to data is modeled, to keep the models simple there is a 2 dimensions array, where the current week is at position 0 since you cannot add negative indexes to an array this limits going to the past. To do this you would need a more complex example, and I think it goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: An example of a model that supports this could be: `{week: 0, data: ['','','','','','','']}`. This would solve the problem of past weeks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I need to dive into this code and try to understand it. I wish there was some ready-to-use component for this type of application - perhaps a calendar or something? If I wish to do changes here I'm not sure how I'll maintain it. Any proposals on libraries/node modules I can use? I'd rather focus on building out my application than being knee-deep in data structure management..

Comment: Question: would the model be simpler if instead of defining the rows dynamically on the client side, I fetch the projects from an api? So returning an array of projects, and then having a row in the table for each item in that fetched array?

Comment: The model would be simpler, that is a fact. You just split the logic in your backend. But overall I think it's not simpler since now you have distributed logic, you have to fetch your api to then render that on the client. I guess there is no right or wrong here, it all depends overall on your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187677/discussion-between-erikvm-and-a-m).